# Given two patterns, search specific directories and print last three file names that match each pattern

Tags: linux, files, find, wildcards

How can I shorten this command?  The goal is to display the latest 3 files that are in the `ABC` folder and match `uvw` in the file name,  then do the same but match `xyz` in the file name.

I'm looking to shorten this since there's a need to add more strings to look for in the future.

```
find . -name 'ABC' | xargs ls | grep -i uvw |sort| tail -n 3; find . -name 'ABC' | xargs ls | grep -i xyz |sort| tail -n 3
```

Example output:

```
2018-06-23T01-23-56.919Z-UVW.gz
2018-06-23T01-29-56.556Z-UVW.gz
2018-06-23T23-26-14.463Z-UVW.gz
2018-08-08T00-16-22.923Z-xyz.js
2018-08-08T00-16-24.517Z-xyz.js
2018-08-08T00-16-25.427Z-xyz.js
```

Comment: @don_crissti is correct.  I edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: @steeldriver, the xargs runs ls on all the folders with the name ABC in them.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
for w (uvw xyz) printf '%s\n' **/ABC/(#i)*$w*(D[-3,-1]:t)
```

- `**/`: any level of subdirectories
- `(#i)`: case insensitive matching for what follows
- `(D[-3,-1]:t)`: glob qualifier
- `D`: include hidden files and look inside hidden dirs like `find` does
- `[-3,-1]`: select only the last 3 (globs are sorted in lexical order by default)
- `:t`: *modifier* that extracts the *tail* of the file path (basename) like your `ls` does.

Note that if there are several ABC directories, the name of those directories will influence the sorting (files in `a/ABC` will appear before those in `b/ABC`).

Comment: Is this a bash command?  I'm getting this error:  
-bash: set: extendedglob: invalid option name

Comment: @kouichi, no, it's zsh syntax, not bash, it says at the start of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea how zsh works but I made a bash script which fits what I need

Answer (score 2):

This will search for any files which match *any* of those fragments:

```
for fragment in ABC UVW xyz; do 
    find . -name "\*${fragment}\*" | sort | tail -n3; 
done
```

If you want to find files which match *all* of them, you can do something like this:

```
find . -name '*ABC*' -a -name '*xyz*' | sort | tail -n3
```

`-a` is `find`'s boolean AND operator.

<sub>For BSD `find`, use `-or` and `-and` rather than `-o` and `-a`.</sub>

Comment: `-a` is the implicit default between the `find` tests.

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to be explicit when possible to prevent possible misreading by future-me.

Comment: Not sure who upvoted here but anyway, please read the question again and revise your post.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are looking for

```
find . -iregex '.*/ABC/[^/]*uvw.*' | sort | tail -n3
```

Here's how it works:

- `-iregex` search in case insensitive mode
- `.*/ABC/` look in any depth for directory ABC (the whole name of dir)
- `[^/]*uvw.*` the name of dir `ABC` is directly followed by a filename containing `uvw` string, not any sub-directories in between

The `sort` and `tail` parts are untouched.

As for adding other patterns: you need to make a loop over this command with all needed strings, or if you need only 3 files regardless from which group they are coming you can combine everything in one command:

```
find . -iregex '.*/ABC/[^/]*\(uvw\|xyz\)[^/]*' | sort | tail -n3
```

Comment: Thanks @jimmij.  'It looks like find . -iregex '.*/ABC/[^/]*uvw.*' | sort | tail -n3'   is similar to  'find . -name 'ABC' | xargs ls | grep -i uvw |sort| tail -n 3', but takes longer to search.  

Maybe I can loop over ABC, DEF, etc. like what you've mentioned.  I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I got what I needed with for loops in a bash script, is it possible to do this in the command line?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ABC DEF
do
  for j in uvw xyz
  do
    x=`find . -iname $i | xargs ls | grep -i $j | sort | tail -n 3`
    echo "$x"
  done
done
```